# Converting pixstruct huggingface model to ONNX format

Tags: python, onnx, huggingface

I want to convert `pix2struct huggingface` base model to `ONNX` format. I write the code for that.

```
import torch
import torch.onnx as onnx
from transformers import AutoModel
import onnx
import onnxruntime
from transformers import Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration, Pix2StructProcessor

# Load the Hugging Face model
model = Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/pix2struct-ai2d-base")

# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Create a sample input tensor
input_ids = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

# Export the model to ONNX format
onnx_path = "model/pix2struct.onnx"
# Prepare a sample input
input_ids = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

# Export the model to ONNX format
dummy_input = input_ids  # Use the sample input as the dummy input
onnx_path = "model/pix2struct.onnx"  # Path to save the ONNX model
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, onnx_path, opset_version=11)

# Load the ONNX model
onnx_model = onnx.load(onnx_path)

# Validate the ONNX model
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)

# Create an ONNX runtime session
session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_path)

# Perform inference using the ONNX model
input_name = session.get_inputs()[0].name
output_name = session.get_outputs()[0].name
input_data = {input_name: input_ids.numpy()}
output = session.run([output_name], input_data)

# Print the output
print(output)
print("Model converted to ONNX successfully!")
```

but in the torch.onnx.export funtion shows a error that dimention of the torch funtion is 2, I want to resolve the error, please help me

I want the help to debug my code.

Comment: Can you add full error to the question?

Comment: Can you help me to convert pix2struct model to onnx format? I tried above code and  it might wrong. So I try once again from scratch